# Reporting in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking for some advice on strategically embedding reports in forms to allow for optimal end-user usage.

In particular, i would like to know if it is possible to have a report embedded into a form but so that the header of the report changes as you scroll down to show the title of the current type of record you are looking at..   As an example, i have a report with about 1000 lines of information relating to 5 category types..  I made a report so that the category type is Always in the header of the report.  Is it possible when viewing this report embedded into a form to have this functionality??

Thank you,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search indicates that Microsoft does have an ActiveX control available which does allow you to embed reports inside forms. It's called the Microsoft ActiveX Snapshot Viewer. Most of the search results indicate that there are vulnerabilities with it, which is often the case with old ActiveX controls.

Even if you do utilize it (which I do not recommend), you're going to run into a problem where you won't know what category the user is viewing, since I'm not aware that Access gives you any way to get that information.

I suggest you use forms instead. Reports are for printing, and in my opinion, for nothing more than that. A preview should allow the user to see very quickly what it will look like, and then print it.

It isn't that hard to build forms that allow users to search/filter. I find that when I build proper searching/filtering forms, my users don't need reports unless they really do need to print something. Forms can be built as read only so they can't change data.

Be aware that even with forms, I don't think it's possible to know what the user is viewing. If they click into a record you would be able to use the OnCurrent event to know what record they are viewing and could likely derive the category from that, but that requires them clicking around in forms. A much more standard way of doing this would be to give them a dropdown which would allow them to select a category and apply a filter to the form (or a subform) to view only that category.

Comment: Thank you..  Your answer and a bit of research put to rest a few concerns..  Just to confirm if you please....  If i have a report embedded in a form, is it possible that if i want to edit or do a zoom on one of its fields, i could do so??  I know what you are thinking,... why not just build a form..  Only that I already have the report built and it is tickling my curiosity if it is possible..

Comment: I don't think any data on a report can edited or clicked on. Zooming is pretty much limited to the default behavior of the magnifying glass.